# Gmail doesn't download 'suspicious' emails from server even though they are legitimate

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I am migrating from G Suite to Personal Gmail via POP3 and am getting tons of these messages.

> "The message "Subject" from Someone (someone@somewhere) contained a
>   virus or suspicious attachment. It was therefore not fetched from your
>   account me@pop3account.com and has been left on the server.
>
> Message ID:
>
> If you wish to write to Fake Company, just click reply and send Fake
>   Company a message.
>
> Thanks,
>
> The Gmail Team

This wouldn't be an issue if these were all fishy emails but most are legitimate emails (e.g. family, work, friends) that I want to make sure that I'll download so I can access them later on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get access to an attachment Gmail regards as a virus?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55040/is-there-any-way-to-get-access-to-an-attachment-gmail-regards-as-a-virus)